# Getting 'CGI (LoadError)' when migrating Tumblr blog to Octopress using Jekyll's Tumblr.rb

Tags: ruby, cgi, tumblr, jekyll

I am using RVM,

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Inside the Octopress directory:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.2.7)
albino (1.3.3)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
bundler (1.0.22 ruby)
chunky_png (1.2.5)
classifier (1.3.3)
compass (0.11.7)
directory_watcher (1.4.1)
fast-stemmer (1.0.0)
ffi (1.0.11)
fssm (0.2.8.1)
haml (3.1.4)
heroku (2.20.1)
jekyll (0.11.2, 0.11.0)
json (1.6.5)
kramdown (0.13.5, 0.13.4)
launchy (2.0.5)
liquid (2.3.0, 2.2.2)
maruku (0.6.0)
mime-types (1.17.2)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.6)
pygments.rb (0.2.4)
rack (1.4.1)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.9.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.0)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
RedCloth (4.2.9)
require (0.2.7)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rubypants (0.2.0)
rubypython (0.5.3)
rubyzip (0.9.6.1)
sass (3.1.14)
sequel (3.32.0)
sinatra (1.2.6)
stringex (1.3.0)
syntax (1.0.0)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
tilt (1.3.3)
```

When I run this:

> $ ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll/migrators/tumblr";Jekyll::Tumblr.process("http://www.my_blog.tumblr.com",
>    format="md")'

I get this:

> `/home/n00shie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in`require': no such file to load -- CGI (LoadError)
>       from /home/n00shie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
>       from /home/n00shie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb:5:in`'
>       from /home/n00shie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
>       from /home/n00shie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in`rescue in require'
>       from /home/n00shie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
>       from -e:1:in`'
>   `

Comment: Any luck? Seems like I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I found it!

open your `/home/n00shie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/lib/jekyll/migrators/tumblr.rb` file and on line #5 change `require 'CGI'` to `require 'cgi'`

Worked for me!

Comment: yeah, same for me. I also opened an issue before sow your A. https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/613